# "Peiran message result: 0" messages using the Allegro 5 game library

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

I am making a game with the Allegro 5 game library for C++ and I am using visual studio 2022. When I run my game these messages are in the output. The messages keep appearing very fast so I think there might be a slight performance loss.

Here are the strange messages:

[Strange messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfoX6.png)

I was making a simple game with the Allegro 5 library. Upon noticing these strange messages, I tried googling them but came to no answer.

Comment: Related: https://community.intel.com/t5/Developing-Games-on-Intel/igdumdim64-dll-is-spamming-Windows-log-via-OutputDebugString/m-p/1422306

Comment: Please turn your image into text so others can find it.

Comment: @kiner_shah Mind making that an answer?

Comment: @Botje, posted an answer, hope that's ok.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://community.intel.com/t5/Developing-Games-on-Intel/igdumdim64-dll-is-spamming-Windows-log-via-OutputDebugString/m-p/1422306

As per this link, the problem occurs because of the UTF-16 string "Peiran message result is: %x" which is present in system files **igdumdim32.dll** and **igdumdim64.dll**.

The problem also appears when running outside Visual Studio, viewed using DebugView (by SysInternals).

igdumdim64.dll is loaded when the program is run. It appears somebody left a debug message on the dlls and it's getting called between 2 and 16 times per second.

The issue seems to be in Intel Ultra HD Graphics Driver. The suggested solution in the link is to update the driver and check again.